# Automatically renaming functions and references to snake_case in PyCharm

Tags: python, formatting, pycharm

I write code in python using PyCharm.
I need to reformat my code and change all function names from camel case to snake_case. I wonder if there is an automatic way to it instead of doing it manually as there are many functions in many files in my code. Note that it is not enough to change the name of the functions in their definition, but all references must be changed as well.

Comment: Just use the refactor feature in PyCharm. The default shortcut should be "shift-F6" when your cursor is on top of the name you want to refactor. Or right click over the name you want to refactor and go to refactor and change the name.

Comment: Read the docs -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/rename-refactorings.html

Comment: I am familiar with the refactor feature. But using it I need to manually go to each function and change it. I want to avoid this since I have a lot of functions to rename. I am looking for some way to do it automatically.

Comment: Which isn't a terrible thing, since you want to make sure that you are changing the right things. However, searching for what you are looking for, don't know how functional these plugins are, but there are options for you [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7160-camelcase). There seems to be a good amount of information in general on this.